# Merge Adapter header crash

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am having problems with the CWAC Merge Adapter: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

This works fine when i am adding views and adapters one after another but it seems that when i try to add two headers one after another it crashes. Here is what i do:

This is the layout for the first header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/unsynced_layoutt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@color/greenish" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unsynced_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/unsynced_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/greenish" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/sync_close_notification"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_bcknd">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/something"
            android:src="@drawable/notification_close_x_green" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout for the second header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey_bcknd"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha="0.25"
        android:background="@color/grey_line" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receipt_header_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_line"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/active_folders"
        android:textColor="#B4AA9E" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/receipt_header_txt"
        android:alpha="0.25"
        android:background="@color/grey_line" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is where i try to physically add it:

```
all_adapter = new MergeAdapter();
        final View notification = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.unsynced_layout, null);
        TextView notification_txt = (TextView) notification.findViewById(R.id.unsynced_txt);
        notification_txt.setText("You have "+unsynced_nr+" unsynced items");
        all_adapter.addView(notification_txt);

        for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++){
            System.out.println("HERE "+i);
            View header1 = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.receipt_list_header, null);
            TextView date_header_txt = (TextView) header1.findViewById(R.id.receipt_header_txt);
            date_header_txt.setText(dates.get(i));
            all_adapter.addView(header1);
            ReceiptDataSource recs1 = new ReceiptDataSource(globalView.getContext());
            recs1.open();
            ArrayList<Receipt> currentReceipts = recs.findReceiptsByDate(dates.get(i), folder_id);
            recs1.close();

            //ReceiptAdapter folder_receipts = new ReceiptAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.receipt_item, R.layout.receipt_incomplete_item, currentReceipts);
            ReceiptCustomAdapter folder_receipts = new ReceiptCustomAdapter(globalView.getContext(), R.layout.receipt_pager,
                    currentReceipts, getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
            all_adapter.addAdapter(folder_receipts);
        }
```

and the stacktrace:

```
08-06 11:54:15.558: E/AndroidRuntime(20408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 11:54:15.558: E/AndroidRuntime(20408): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
08-06 11:54:15.558: E/AndroidRuntime(20408):    at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1170)
08-06 11:54:15.558: E/AndroidRuntime(20408):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1252)
```

If i comment the line:

```
all_adapter.addView(notification_txt);
```

the code is not crashing anymore.

Any suggestions highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How looks your `getView()` method in `ListAdapter`?

Comment: i don't think that's relevant, the code crashes when adding the view, not the adapter...

Comment: i thinks that its relevant if in your `getView()` methods you are returning for example only `TextView` instead of whole row `View`.

Comment: I am returning a whole row View, thanks for your observation, i didn't even think of that:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this issue because the `MergeAdapter` expects `AbsListView.LayoutParams`. Try this:

```
final View notification = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unsynced_layout, null);
TextView notification_txt = (TextView) notification.findViewById(R.id.unsynced_txt);
notification_txt.setText("You have "+unsynced_nr+" unsynced items");
AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
notification_txt.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
all_adapter.addView(notification_txt);
```

But, in case you are trying to simply add the whole view to your mergeadapter, then instead of `all_adapter.addView(notification_txt);` you could say: `all_adapter.addView(notification);`

Comment: are you familiar with CWAC Merge Adapter? I pasted the link to the GitHub source but it would help if you had previously worked with this...

Comment: I've used it in a project and was happy with it. I had a case where I needed a listview and some other views to be scrollable vertically and mergeadapter was great for this.

Comment: Well it's the same for me, i have a list with headers, so the format is: Header then adapter, header then adapter, functionality that i achieved by using the for loop. that works just fine. thing is i need to add an extra header to this at the top. Could it be problematic that it's a different layout? That's what i am not sure, if you need to keep the format: header + adapter...

Comment: You don't need to keep that format - the merge adapter is very flexible when it comes to what can be used. I managed to have the same case: header + header + list + header + list. It should be straight-forward, unless you're not doing anything extravagant :).

Comment: One thing to note here: why are you inflating views only to extract a TextView from it, instead of creating instances of `TextViews` on the fly?

Comment: that's the thing, the headers have completely different layouts... and i only need to update the content of the textview...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34891/discussion-between-gunar-and-adrian-olar)

Comment: @AdrianOlar: The key is gunar's last sentence. You are inflating a layout, ripping some widget out of that layout, then attempting to add it as a header. I would have expected a different error ("view already has a parent"), but that's definitely not going to work.

Comment: @Mark: We discussed about it, AdrianOlar had a typo in code, he wanted to add the whole view, not the TextView. Bytheway, it's a great library! Thanks! :)